# Get customer details by using Authentication Token

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, webapi, token

I use this Magento 2 rest api to get customer token:

```
curl -X POST "https://my.project/rest/V1/integration/customer/token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d "{"username":"me@awesome.com", "password":"d00l1tle"}"
```

i successfully got the token, and i pass the token in header when i access my custom magento 2 webapi

```
Authorization: Bearer <authentication token>
```

**webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/test/most/" method="GET">
      <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\TestRepositoryInterface" method="getTest"/>
      <resources>
          <resource ref="self"/>
      </resources>
  </route>
```

i want to retrieve the customer information in my `getTest()` function base on customer token which is use as Authorization header

Answer (score 2):

> **webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/test/most/" method="GET">
  <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\TestRepositoryInterface" method="getTest"/>
  <resources>
      <resource ref="self"/>
  </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
 </route>
```

**in this API call you'll get customer ID and based on ID you can get Customer data.**

---

**Another solution**

```
$ch = curl_init('dev.magento2.com/rest/V1/customers/me');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `anonymous` resource you have to add the 
`Authorization`: Bearer to your request.

```
curl -X POST "https://my.project/rest/V1/integration/customer/token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -H 'authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXX' \
     -d "{"username":"me@awesome.com", "password":"d00l1tle"}"
```

This **XXXXXXXX** is token id, which  you **have to generate from admin>System>Intregation**

Comment: my bad, i use `self` not `anonymous` , check my updated question